# Oracle DBMS 12c, How to create a user that can create tables

Tags: database, oracle

I installed Oracle 12c on my system, intending to develop a few simple tables. How do I create a simply user that can create and manipulate tables? Right now the only way I can access the dbms is with sqlplus "/as sysdba".

I created a tablespace. But when I try to create a user with that tablespace as it's default, it tells me the tablespace does not exist. I run "select * from V$tablespace" and I do see my tablespace.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here. I've been reading over Oracle's documentation, nothing seems to work. Specifically, user creation. The examples Oracle has cause me errors, complains about pluggable databases. After reading, pluggable databases are a new feature of 12c, so you have to append C## to the front user names. I think this makes it a 'common' user, although I'm not sure what that really is. Regardless, even using "C##test" it can't find my tablespace. :-(

```
SQL> create tablespace DBClassSpace;

SQL> create user C##test
  2  identified by secret
  3  default tablespace DBCLASSSPACE
  4  quota 10M on DBCLASSSPACE
  5  temporary tablespace TEMP;
create user C##test
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-65048: error encountered when processing the current DDL statement in
pluggable database PLUGDBCLASS
ORA-00959: tablespace 'DBCLASSSPACE' does not exist

SQL> select user from dual;

USER
------------------------------
SYS

SQL> select * from V$tablespace;

       TS# NAME                           INC BIG FLA ENC     CON_ID
---------- ------------------------------ --- --- --- --- ----------
         1 SYSAUX                         YES NO  YES              1
         0 SYSTEM                         YES NO  YES              1
         2 UNDOTBS1                       YES NO  YES              1
         4 USERS                          YES NO  YES              1
         3 TEMP                           NO  NO  YES              1
         0 SYSTEM                         YES NO  YES              2
         1 SYSAUX                         YES NO  YES              2
         2 TEMP                           NO  NO  YES              2
         0 SYSTEM                         YES NO  YES              3
         1 SYSAUX                         YES NO  YES              3
         2 TEMP                           NO  NO  YES              3

       TS# NAME                           INC BIG FLA ENC     CON_ID
---------- ------------------------------ --- --- --- --- ----------
         3 USERS                          YES NO  YES              3
         5 DBCLASSSPACE                   YES NO  YES              1
```

...

```
SQL> select tablespace_name from cdb_tablespaces;   

 TABLESPACE_NAME
    ------------------------------
    SYSTEM
    SYSAUX
    UNDOTBS1
    TEMP
    USERS
    DBCLASSSPACE
    SYSTEM
    SYSAUX
    TEMP
    USERS

    10 rows selected.

    SQL> create user C##test
      2  identified by secret
      3  default tablespace DBCLASSSPACE
      4  quota 10M on DBCLASSSPACE
      5  temporary tablespace TEMP;
    create user C##test
    *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-65048: error encountered when processing the current DDL statement in
    pluggable database PLUGDBCLASS
    ORA-00959: tablespace 'DBCLASSSPACE' does not exist
```

Comment: Did you create the tablespace, and are you querying that view, in the root container or in a pluggable DB? You wantto create it, and then the user, in the PDB rather than the root. Are you following examples from the 12c docs, or something earler? It might help to include a link to those and the errors you are getting.

Comment: Here is what I'm following: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8003.htm#SQLRF01503

Comment: I added a tablespace. I'm in the SYS database, which is the root container, correct? I first read the term "pluggable DB' today. How to I use a tablespace in Oracle? I can't find anything on that.

Comment: `sys` is a schema.  The container database and each pluggable database will have a `sys` schema.  It would be very helpful to show us the exact command(s) you are running and the exact error message(s) you are getting.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I've added specifics.

Answer (score 0):

You need assign some volume in the tablespace for a user to create table. 
If you are in cdb$root:

```
CREATE USER C##U1 
        IDENTIFIED BY password 
        DEFAULT TABLESPACE SYSAUX 
        QUOTA 10M ON SYSAUX 
        TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp;
```

Comment: I did essentially just that:

create user C##test
identified by secret
default tablespace DBCLASSSPACE
quota 10M onDBCLASSSPACE
temporary tablespace TEMP;

Comment: DBCLASSSPACE space is not a common tablespace which means it does not exist in PDB PLUGDBCLASS. Please query the view  CDB_TABLESPACES and assign the user to a proper common tablespace. SYSAUX is a common table space.

Comment: Hi Dere. I've tried this. I added my commands above, the second block.

Comment: Like I said, DBCLASSSPACE is a local tablespace which does not exist in the PDB. If you do select con_id, tablespace_name from cdb_tablespaces;  you will find DBCLASSSPACE  does not exist in all PDBs. Please use SYSTEM or SYSAUX instead if it is okay.

Comment: Why to append "C##"?